# Different values in bash and Zabbix WebUI

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, zabbix

I would like to ask you for any hint regarding following issue.

I'm using external scripts for checks in Zabbix 2.2. I try to develop some script which will get timestamp of certain file on remote storage. The script is working fine in CLI of the Zabbix server, but in Zabbix I see **0** (zero) value only.

I identified that the main issue is in the line with ssh command where I try to connect to remote storage and get the information.

The scripts look like:

```
TIMESTAMP_REMOTE_FILE=$(ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no -i $KEY_FILE "$REMOTE_USER"@"$HOSTNAME" "stat --format='%Y' $FILE ")
echo TIMESTAMP_REMOTE_FILE
```

The output in linux console looks like:

```
[user1@hostname1 externalscripts]$ sudo -u zabbixsrv ./days_since_last_backup.sh
1436745682
[user1@hostname1 externalscripts]$
```

But in Zabbix (Latest values) it looks like:

```
Timestamp               Value
2015.Jul.13 15:04:25    0
```

When I change the value TIMESTAMP_REMOTE_FILE for some certain value (example 100000), the value is visible in Zabbix as well.

```
Timestamp               Value
2015.Jul.13 16:04:25    100000
```

Have somebody been facing the same issue like me? Has got somebody any hint how to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure you passed the correct file name in zabbix?

Comment: Are sure that item setting "Type of information" is text?

Comment: Are you sure, that the zabbix user has the permission to access the ssh keyfile?

Comment: yes, I'm sure that zabbix is using the key file - in case that I change the permissions or ownership then the script is asking for password of the key (AFAIK because he cannot access it correctly).

Comment: To Jan Garaj: yes, in Zabbix I'm using for debugging purposes type of information as text. I expect that when the script will be executed correctly, I will change it.

Comment: well, the issue was in path of the key file - thank you guys for help. I will summarize my solution and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I examined the described issue more in deep. I've enabled logging on to file by using

```
TIMESTAMP_REMOTE_FILE=$(
  ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no 
    -i $KEY_FILE "$REMOTE_USER"@"$HOSTNAME" 
    "stat --format='%Y' $FILE " > /tmp/zabbix_script.log 
  )
echo TIMESTAMP_REMOTE_FILE
```

There was quite clearly stated that the ssh command is trying to find out the file with private key. Because the script is run from command line from directory where the script is located, no issue appeared there.

Thank all of you for contributing ... every hint is counting